# AngularJS: Nested named views from different modules

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, nested-views

I'm using angular-ui-router to load nested named views.

In the index.html file I have an unnamed view and a named one.

Index.html:

```
<div ui-view="header"></div>       
<div ui-view=""></div>
```

I load header.html to named view **header**. The header view has two named views **contactsSearch** and **countries**.

Header.html:

```
 <div ui-view="contactsSearch"></div>
 <div ui-view="countries"></div>
```

In the unnamed view of the index.html file I want to load contacts.html.

Contacts.html:

```
Contacts List
```

I use three modules: **myApp**, **countries** and **contacts**. I've configured the routes for each module.

**MyApp** module:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.state', 'contacts', 'countries'])
.config(['$stateProvider', '$routeProvider',  
    function ($stateProvider, $routeProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state("home",
        {
            url: "/home",
            abstract: true,
            views: {
                'header': {
                    template: "<div class ='row' ui-view ='countriesList'></div><div class ='row' ui-view ='contactsSearch'></div>"
                },
                "": {
                    template: "<div ui-view></div>"
                }
            }
        }); 

    }]);
```

**Countries** module:

```
angular.module('countries', ['ui.state'])
.config(['$stateProvider', '$routeProvider',  
    function ($stateProvider, $routeProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state("home.countries", {
            url: "/countries",
            views: {
                'countriesList': {
                    template: "<p>Countries</p>"
                }
            }
        });

    }])
    .run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams', function ($rootScope,   $state, $stateParams) {
        $rootScope.$state = $state;
        $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
        $state.transitionTo('home.countries');
    }]);
```

**Contacts** module:

```
angular.module('contacts', ['ui.state'])
.config(['$stateProvider', '$routeProvider',  
    function ($stateProvider, $routeProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state("home.contacts", {//should be loaded to the unnamed view in index.html
            url: "",
            views: {
                'contactsList': {
                    template: "<p>Contacts List</p>"
                }
            }
        })
        .state("home.contactsSearch", {
            url: "/contactsSearch",
            views: {
                'contactsSearch': {
                    template: "<p>Contacts Search</p>"
                }
            }
        });

    }])
    .run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams', function ($rootScope,   $state, $stateParams) {
        $rootScope.$state = $state;
        $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
        $state.transitionTo('home.contactsSearch');
    }]);
```

My code is not correct because nothing is being displayed and I cannot figure out why. After some investigation, I've found out that a parent can have only one state, but I need **home.contacts**, **home.contactsSearch** and **home.countries** to have the same parent: **home**.

Can someone please help me with this?

I've created a jsfiddle for more details: https://jsfiddle.net/cjtnmbjw/3/

Thank you

Comment: Any reason for having separate modules? I forked and cleaned up your fiddle to get it working and displaying the header view: https://jsfiddle.net/officert/34wbs0s5/37/

Comment: Thank you @officert, but I want to use modularization because the application I'm working on will be a large one and I want to organize it by function instead of type. I was also able to make it work the way you did it, but the problem is when I have multiple modules, each one with its own configuration file.

Comment: Did you have any luck with this? I've just hit the same problem.